# MySQL date query only returns one year, when multiple exist

Tags: mysql, date, count

I'm a part-time designer/developer with a part-time photography business. I've got a database of photos with various bits of metadata attached. I want to query the database and return a list of the years that photos were taken, and the quantity of photos that were taken in that year.

In short, I want a list that looks like this:

```
2010 (35 photos)
2009 (67 photos)
2008 (48 photos)
```

Here's the query I'm using:

```
SELECT YEAR(date) AS year, COUNT(filename) as quantity FROM photos WHERE visible='1' GROUP BY 'year' ORDER BY 'year' DESC
```

Instead of churning out all the possible years (the database includes photos from 2010-2008), this is the sole result:

```
2010 (35 photos)
```

I've tried a lot of different syntax but at this point I'm giving in and asking for help!

Answer (score 3):

Don't single-quote `year`.
That is telling MySQL that `year` is a string; which it isn't.

In addition, don't use an alias in the `GROUP BY`.

Try this:

```
SELECT YEAR(date) AS year, COUNT(filename) as quantity 
FROM photos 
WHERE visible='1' 
GROUP BY YEAR(date)
ORDER BY YEAR(date) DESC
```

Edit:
In most RDBMSes the `SELECT` clause is interpreted last.
So we cannot use a column alias in other clauses of that particular query.

Comment: Yes! It works perfectly and I understand the mistake now. Thank you, Adam.

Comment: Follow-up question: why not use the alias? It does work and seems more efficient, but maybe not... ?

Comment: @Bowman: added more info on why not to use an alias in `GROUP BY`.  Your query might work in MySQL, but perhaps not in another RDBMS.  If you're sticking with MySQL, that may not be an issue for you.  Glad the query is working now :-)

Comment: Excellent. I am using MySQL but I appreciate the clarification. Thanks for taking the time to explain.

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL Solution:

```
SELECT 
   [text] = 
      cast(year(date) as varchar) + ' ('+cast(count(filename) as varchar) + 
      'photo'+case when count(filename)>1 then 's' else '' end + ')'
   ,
   [year] = year(date)
FROM photos 
WHERE  visible='1' 
GROUP BY YEAR(date)
ORDER BY YEAR(date) DESC
```